# How to detect if a particular slide with a class is in the view?

Tags: javascript, html, css, slider, swiper.js

I have `slidesPerView: 3` and `slidesPerGroup: 3` initialised, and I have a class called `.section-xx-start` to separate each 'section' within a timeline sort of a carousel, and everytime the slide with the class .section-xx-start is in the view (no matter which position, 1st 2nd or 3rd), the background colour changes. I can't seem to find a parameter/method for this. This is what I have so far:

```
<div class="swiper-slide section-one-start">
    ...
</div>
<div class="swiper-slide">
    ...
</div>
<div class="swiper-slide">
    ...
</div>
<div class="swiper-slide">
    ...
</div>
<div class="swiper-slide">
    ...
</div>
<div class="swiper-slide section-two-start">
    ...
</div>

<script>
    var mySwiper = new Swiper ('.swiper-container', {
        slidesPerView: 3,
        slidesPerGroup: 3,
        spaceBetween: 50,
        grabCursor: true,
        navigation: {
            nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
            prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
        }
    });

    const nextButton = document.querySelector('.swiper-button-next');
    const prevButton = document.querySelector('.swiper-button-prev');

    function changeBgColor() {
       if(slideWithClassIsInViewPort) {
           this.style.backgroundColor = "var(--navy)";
       } else {
           //do nothing
       }
    }

    nextButton.addEventListener('click', changeBgColor);
    prevButton.addEventListener('click', changeBgColor);
</script>
```

I am just unsure on how to apply that "slideWithClassIsInViewPort" part. If there's any other suggestions to improve my code, please suggest! Appreciate any help!

Edit: Visit (deleted) to see slider.

Answer (score 1):

You could just check the display state for the current slide, if you are using the CSS rule display to hide/show slides.

Example:

```
if(slide.style.display ='block'){
  // do whatever
}
```

Edit:

Im not sure if you already fixed it or not, but in case you didnt, here is a code in your *main.js* file which logs the current index of the slider to the console.

```
const button = document.querySelector('.swiper-button-next');

function consoleLog() {
    console.log(mySwiper.activeIndex);
}

button.addEventListener('click', consoleLog);
```

When clicking next in your slide, i assume the number of columns it has showed appears. And since each slide shows 3 columns each, the index probly works around that, there of 3, 6, 9, 12 etc. So to set the background different or whatever you are trying to do, for each slide, you could do something like this:

Example:

```
var currentIndex = mySwiper.activeIndex;

function changeBg(){
if(currentIndex == 3) // second slide {
slider.style.background='white';
}
if(currentIndex == 6) // third slide {
slider.style.background='blue';
} 

button.addEventListener('click', changeBg);
```

There is probaly better ways to do it, but i dont have much time right now so thats the best i could do.

Comment: I'm not using the CSS display rule to see if its active or not. See edit to see the url of website and slider.

Comment: When i go to your website and click next in the slider, it executes a function which logs the current index of the slide to the console, so i suppose you already fixed it.

Comment: Hey thanks, I think that's pretty much it! Thanks again for the help!